# expected values of identically distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be identically distributed random variables on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$.

Then, if I let $F_X$ and $F_Y$ denote the distribution functions of $X$ and $Y$, respectively, I know that $X$ and $Y$ being identically distributed means that $F_X(t) = F_Y(t)$ for all $t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then, I have the following questions.

1. From this definition, how does one show that $E[X] = E[Y]$?
2. More in general, it is true that $$\int_K X \, d\mathbb{P}  = \int_K Y \, d\mathbb{P}$$
   for any $K \in \Sigma$?

Answer (score 4):

The second statement is false.  Suppose you flip a fair coin, $X$ is the indicator of "heads" and $Y$ is the indicator of "tails".  Then they are both identically distributed but if you let $K$ be the event "heads", their integrals over $K$ are clearly not equal.

In fact, the equality for all $K$ holds iff $X=Y$ almost surely, which is a far stronger condition than "identically distributed".  To see this, consider $K = \{X > Y\}$ and $K = \{X < Y\}$.

Answer (score 3):

You can show that 
$$E(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x\, dF_X(x).$$
This'll do it.